# Validate against NaN values in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working in a Rails 5.1 application and simply need to write a validation against `Float::NAN` and `BigDecimal::NAN` but can't seem to find one that will actually work. [So far I have tried what I have thought would work from the Rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html):

```rb
validates :my_column, exclusion: { in: [BigDecimal::NAN, Float::NAN], message: 'NaN value is not allowed.' }
validates :my_column, numericality: { other_than: BigDecimal::NAN }
```

But in both cases I'm still able to save a NaN value into the database.

Comment: Why is it possible to pass `Float::NAN` or `BigDecimal::NAN` to the model in the first place?

Comment: Client side input. I'll need to add validation on that side also, but would protect the DB server side too.

Comment: Did you ever try to pass something to a Rails app that ended up as `Float::NAN` in a `float` type column? I would be surprised that was even possible and if Rails would allow that without raising an error.

Comment: @spickermann not why but how is it possible to pass `Float::NAN`. OP however you are getting this a custom validation such as `validate :my_column_nan` and `def my_column_nan; errors.add(:my_column, 'NaN value is not allowed.') if self.my_column.to_f.nan?; end` will solve it

Comment: Yes, passing `NaN` in the form input is currently storing the value into the database as NaN (Postgres numeric column). Retrieving the model record from the database then sets the value as `BigDecimal::NAN`.

Comment: @engineersmnky I was hoping to avoid a custom validation, as this will need to be used on a few columns, but I might end up needing to going that route if there's no other options.

Comment: @engineersmnky has the right approach. Keep in mind that `Float::NAN == Float::NAN`, `BigDecimal::NAN == BigDecimal::NAN`, and `Float::NAN == BigDecimal::NAN` are all false so you have to manually call `#nan?` to find NaNs.

Comment: @Travis then create a [custom validator](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) then you can just add something like `validates :my_column, nan: false`